Teams Owner connection to SharePoint severed, anyway to restore this?
I'm a user with no powershell or admin centre access (but I could contact someone who does).
Our SharePoint site (made from a Teams team) was having strange member behaviour where they couldn't edit pages. We couldn't resolve it so contacted MS.
The agent had a call with me and told me to delete one of the Owner groups displaying in the permissions list. I was skeptical and kept saying were they sure because I think it's related to the Teams permissions but they still had me delete both the Member and Owner domain groups, leaving behind only the SharePoint equivalent groups.
This immediately made all Members lose access to files, and all Owners lost access.
I was luckily able to find the Members group and add them into the SharePoint group, but not back into the permissions list.
The Owners group is gone completely though. And I had to manually add all the Owners into the SharePoint group for owners.
It's too late for a point in time restoration now, which they should've suggested immediately, so what other solutions are there? I am not a tech specialist and so I did not want to be arrogant to continue arguing against deleting those groups with someone from MS, but now I wish I had been because this is a mess.
I'm thankful for any clues to help resolve this.

You really need to talk with your admins.

They have no idea what to do, hence asking here. In fact, they've upgraded to just not replying to the Microsoft agents any more. (the Admins sent me to the agents)

I'm sorry you're dealing with that, but that indicates an organizational issue that is impacting a technical need, and the real problem is the organizational issue. This site is not about enterprise-class cloud systems. You may try asking on ServerFault, but they are going to want to talk with the admins too.

Thanks, I'll try asking there. It's incredible to me that MS would have such an important group just there deletable and not recoverable, and that they have agents who don't recognise them and advise customers to delete it without double-checking on a test site first.
